# Magento 1.9 : send multiple images as attachements in Email

Tags: magento-1.9, multiple-file-upload, email-attachment

I have implemented send email in single image file as attachment. but now i want to send multiple images as attchment in email.How can i acheive that? if anyone can help me.

I have tried below code for single image send in email and that is working fine.

I have used a request quote folder as requestquote in media directory for saving for uploaded images. There is an array of custom variables to be passed to transactional email.

```
$uploadfilename = '';

if( !empty($_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"])  )
{

    $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"]));
    $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

    $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["name"]); 
    $source_upl         = $_FILES["rfloorplanattachment"]["tmp_name"];
    $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
    if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
        @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
    }
}


$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

$templateId = 3;
$sender = Array('name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail);


$requestquotesvars = array(
            'firmname'     =>  $customer->getFirstname()
        );


$emaiName = 'Request Quote Firms';

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
$transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
{
$transactionalEmail->getMail()
                ->createAttachment(
        file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename),
        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        basename($uploadfilename)
    );
}
$transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $companymail, $emailName, $requestquotesvars, $storeId);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);

   unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code..

```
 if( !empty($_FILES["customerimageuploads"]["name"][0]))
        {
            $total = count($_FILES['customerimageuploads']['name']);
            for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
                $image_ext           = end(explode('.',$_FILES["customerimageuploads"]["name"][$i]));
                $allowed_ext         = array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');
                $uploadfilename      = $_FILES["customerimageuploads"]["name"][$i]; 
                $source_upl          = $_FILES["customerimageuploads"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $target_path_upl     = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  

                if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
                    @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
                }
            }
        }    

$templateId = 3;

 /* FOR EMAIL LOOP */
        for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
                $uploadfilename      = $_FILES["customerimageuploads"]["name"][$i]; 
                if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) )
                {
                    $transactionalEmail->getMail()
                                ->createAttachment(
                        file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename),
                        Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                        basename($uploadfilename)
                    );
                }
        }
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            $transactionalEmail->setTemplateSubject($senderSubject); 
            /*  Admin email */
            $transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $toEmail, $toName, $params, $storeId);
```

Comment: It works as expected. Thanks :) happy coding...!!!